# Using USB security dongle of an appliance in VM machine

Tags: penetration-testing, dongle, luks

We have a customized Ubuntu on an appliance, the Disk is encrypted using “CryptSetup luks” and the passphrase comes from interaction with a **USB security dongle**.

I have no root access, but with a live OS I took a full dump of disk and then run it in a VMware Workstation. It seems everything is Ok but the system stops for “crypt setup” passphrase and says “bad password” means that the password is incorrect.

Even I have changed the mac address of VM ETH to make it same as appliance ETH as I was thinking the dongle makes passphrase using MAC address.

Is there something else that varies from appliance to VMware machine which I can change so that the dongle works on VMware?

Comment: What's on the USB drive?

Comment: @evilSnobu there is nothing on usb dongle, its a security dongle and not a normal drive. it is a USB Token device that interacts with the machine and gives the passphrase.